# Menubar menus are below another div?

Tags: html, css, hover

I have a problem with an HTML Menubar menus, the menus of the menubars are presented below another div, so are not displayed:

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: How about some css and a little fiddle?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Increase `z-index` for the navigation menu.  This will ensure that any objects that are overlapping them, shall make room for the navigation to come one level up.

For Instance,

```
z-index: 1;
```

***PS:** 1 is an example value. You can increase it to whatever value you want.*

Answer (score 1):

put `z-index:1000;` in css  menu